# Speed up load to Oracle database through python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to dump csv files into my table using cx_Oracle and python. But it's unbearably slowly (500 records in 336 secs). Kindly let me if there's any other method faster than this. Code is below

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import time


connection_string = '{}/{}@//{}:{}/{}'.format(user_name, password, host_name, port, service_name)
engine = cx_Oracle.connect(connection_string)


start_time = time.time()

t = pd.read_sql(con=engine, sql='select * from students where rownum < 18000')

print(t.shape)

t.to_sql(con=engine, name='students_new', if_exists='append', index=False)

print("Finished in : " + str(round(time.time() - start_time, 2)))
```

Comment: skip the python nonsense and use the csv as an oracle [external table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html#GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E)

Comment: @OldProgrammer i have to automate the process and python is my best bet

Comment: External tables are great, but need to be on the DB server machine, which isn't so practical for most people.

Answer (score 2):

The example code you gave doesn't match the written question.

If you want to load data from as CSV file into Oracle database using Python, the straight cx_Oracle example is in the [Loading CSV Files into Oracle Database](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#loading-csv-files-into-oracle-database) section of the manual.  You need to use `executemany()` to upload as much data as possible with each call to the database.

To cut & paste from the manual:

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

. . .

# Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition
cursor.setinputsizes(None, 25)

# Adjust the batch size to meet your memory and performance requirements
batch_size = 10000

with open('testsp.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    sql = "insert into test (id,name) values (:1, :2)"
    data = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        data.append((line[0], line[1]))
        if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
            data = []
    if data:
        cursor.executemany(sql, data)
    con.commit()
```